# Manipulate object after generic 'create_object' view (python/django)

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

Is it possible to manually add field entries to an object that has been created with the generic view?

Eg,

```
from django.views.generic.create_update import create_object

def create_thing(request):

    queryset = Things.objects.all()

    #Somehow pass something to tell the view to
    #assign Thing.author=request.user...

    return create_object(
        request,
        queryset,
        form_class = ThingForm,
        template_name = 'thing_template.html',
        )
```

Ta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no. You'll have to write your own view.

[Here's the source](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/create_update.py#L100) - you can see that there's no callback or anything, and nothing that gets passed both the request (so you can access request.user) and the new_object that you could possibly override to do the assignment.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if it was possible to manipulate the request in someway. Ie fake a POST containing the required assignment. Probably a brittle solution.